# Issue in appending data in $scope.result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a controller that iterates pages to create scrolling.

```
    var i=1; 
  $scope.result=[];
  $scope.loadMore = function(){
  $http.get( "http://test.website.com/api/search/"+i).success(function(response){
    i++; 
    $scope.result.push(response);
    console.log(response);
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.result = response; 
    });

    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  });
  }
```

I want to push the returned json object into result in my view:

```
   <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="post($event,res)"  ng-repeat="res in result" ng-model="text"  ng-controller="recommendedJobsCtrl" >
```

I also added the following to my view, at the bottom:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

the data in the console.log shows the correct information but i don't think it is being pushed to the result. Can someone please advise?

My console.log outputs this

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

and ech object contains:

```
"id":1396702,
      "employer_id":74801,
      "external_id":null,
      "view":449,
      "apply":22,
      "status":1,
      "rank":1,
      "type":"C",
      "notification_type":4,
      "package":2,
      "locality":"MY",
      "locality_city":"Kuala Lumpur",
      "category":"adm",
      "subcategory":null,
      "level":0,
      "experience":0,
      "country":"MY",
      "zip":null,
      "area":"Kuala Lumpur",
      "state":null,
      "city":null,
      "salary_min":1000,
      "salary_max":1100,
      "salary_period":2,
      "salary_currency":"MYR",
      "logo_url":"\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/JHP-S3\/uploads\/image\/90821\/1owQih5MsM\/plogo",
      "banner_url":"",
      "company_url":null,
      "company_email":"shareen@mymillenniumjobs.com",
      "company":"1Millennium International Sdn Bhd",
      "industry":0,
      "title":"Telephone Operator - Kuala Lumpur",
      "summary":null,
      "description":" 
Attend to customers' incoming calls and provide solutions in a timely manner.<\/li>\n 
SPM Cerificate<\/li>\n 
Good spoken English<\/li>\n 
5 days work - Monday to Friday<\/li>\n 
Working hours - 8:45am to 5:45pm<\/li>\n 
People oriented and able to work well in team<\/li>\n 
Basic salary 1000 + attendance allowance<\/li>\n 
Working Location - around Kuala Lumpur (LRT or monorail accessible)<\/li>\n 
Calling all school leavers keen in part-time work<\/li>\n<\/ul>",
      "published_at":"2016-07-11 01:41:52",
      "refreshed_at":"2016-07-11 01:41:52",
      "created_at":"2016-04-04 06:55:17",
      "updated_at":"2016-07-11 01:49:28"
   },
```

Comment: By the way why do you have `ng-model="text"` in your div? I think this could be the problem since it places a watch on the div basically for `$scope.text`.

Comment: I must have made a mistake writing it, i removed it but I still have the same issue, it's not pushing to result

Comment: Ok but can you share some more of your html code so we can understand the whole picture of what's happening and what should happen?

Comment: I edited the question, all the information is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Make sure response is not contain any object. if it contain in data object then you can use `data.response`

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item.title}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="1%">
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
.controller('yourCtrl', function ($http, $scope) {
    var i=1; 
    $scope.result=[];   
     $scope.loadMore = function () {
            $http.get( "http://test.website.com/api/search/"+i).then(function (data) {
                $scope.result = data;
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

            });
        }


        $scope.categories = [];
        $http.get( "http://test.website.com/api/search/"+i).then(function (returnData) {
            $scope.result = returnData;
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })



  })
```

Comment: I tried it but then I got a $digest error so i replaced $apply with timeout. But it is still the same issue. the data won't load in my result

Comment: would you please show your console of response data

Comment: have you used this in ionic ?

Comment: yes, it's in ionic. I edited the question. ALl the information is in there